# Reactjs, How to make scroll stay at current position when scrollable div extends

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a react Chat app and I was going to use the infinite scroll but it doesn't work the way I wanted it to. So I built one myself. I used useref to determine the height and if it reaches to the top it will add more chats. kinda like fb messenger's chat. The problem now is that when I add more chats, once it reaches the top, the scroll bar will continue to go up and not stick in place unlike how react-infinite scroll works.
[image]

May I know how I can go through this? Here is my code.
for the scroll:

```
const onScroll = () => {
        if (topDiv.current) {
            const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = topDiv.current;
            if(scrollTop === 0){
                props.fecthMoreChat()
            }
        }
    };
return(
     <div id='scrollableDiv' ref={topDiv} onScroll={()=> onScroll()} style={{height:'100%', padding:'20px', display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', backgroundColor:'#efefef', overflowY:'scroll'}}>
          {/* <div style={{visibility:'hidden'}} ref={topDiv}></div> */}
             {currentChat.map((chat, index)=>{
                 return(
                     <div key={index} style={{textAlign:chat.sender===username?'right':'left'}}>
                         {chat.message}
                     </div>
                 )
             })}
         <div style={{visibility:'hidden'}} ref={botMsg}></div>
     </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer was actually pretty simple. I just took the current scroll height, saved it in a variable, then waited for the re-render and took the new scroll height. Basically, just subtract the old scroll height with the new scroll height and use that number to set scroll by using `scrollTo()`. Here is the code:

```
const onScroll = async () => {
        if (chatDiv.current) {
            const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = chatDiv.current;
            if(scrollTop === 0){
                const pastScroll = scrollHeight
                await props.fecthMoreChat()
                const currentScroll = (await chatDiv.current.scrollHeight-pastScroll) 
                await chatDiv.current.scrollTo(0, currentScroll)
            }
        }
    };
```